# How to fix Application.LocalUserAppDataPath in the .NET browser-wasm runtime?

Tags: .net, browser-wasm

I have some existing code which accesses `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` which I am porting to .NET's browser-wasm runtime.

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(sPath) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath)
```

In browser-wasm this property appears to be an empty string, which breaks the code using it (`CreateDirectory` throws "The value cannot be an empty string.").

What can I do so that it returns something sensible?